# Problemas al imprimir en el arcihvo.txt

Tags: c++

Ayuda
Mi programa solo crea el archivo.txt vacío, me podrían ayudar a hacer que los datos que ingrese en el se guarden en el archivo.

```
void agregar(){
    system("cls");
    system ("color 3e");

    fflush(stdin);
    printf("\n%d.Nombre de contacto:  ", (cont+1));
    gets(control[cont].nom);//getline (cin,nom)

    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"\nApellido de contacto:  ", (cont+1);
    gets(control[cont].ap);

    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"\nTelofono:  ";
    scanf("%d", &control[cont].tel);

    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"\nDirecci\242n:  ";
    gets(control[cont].dir);

    fflush(stdin);
    cout<<"\nDepartamento:  ";
    gets(control[cont].dep);

    cont++;

}


void escribir ()
    {
    ofstream archivo;

    archivo.open("guia telefonica.txt",ios::out);//abrir el archivo


    archivo.close();//cerrar el archivo
}
```

Comment: ¡Guau! 318 líneas de código. Por favor revisa [ask] y [mcve]; intenta depurar el código que tienes, ver donde está el problema (¿no te monta bien la estructura de datos en memoria?¿te la monta bien pero no te escribe?) y poner solo **el código relevante a tu problema**. Poca gente por aquí tendrá la paciencia para revisarte gratis +300 líneas de programa.

Comment: bueno gracias ahorita lo arreglo

Answer (score 1):

> Ayuda Mi programa solo crea el archivo.txt vacío

No se qué esperabas que tuviera el archivo si, literalmente, lo único que haces es abrirlo para acto seguido cerrarlo:

```
void escribir ()
    {
    ofstream archivo;

    archivo.open("guia telefonica.txt",ios::out);//abrir el archivo


    archivo.close();//cerrar el archivo
}
```

Te propongo escribir cosas en el archivo, así no estará vacío:

```
void escribir ()
{
    using namespace std;

    if (ofstream archivo{"guia telefonica.txt"})
    {
        archivo << "Datos, datos, datos!\n";
    }
}
```

Como puedes ver no he llamado a `std::ofstream::close`, esto es porque se llama automáticamente al salir de la función ya que esa clase sigue el [patrón RAII](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/RAII).

Comment: muchas gracias pero como podria hacer que lo que se escriba en la funcion agregar lo guarde en el archivo.txt

Comment: Escribiendo cosas en la función agregar que vayan a parar al archivo igual que en el ejemplo que he puesto.

Answer (score 0):

Una vez abierto el archivo lo único que tienes que hacer añadirle datos utilizando el operador `<<`. [Igual que como lo harías con `cin`](http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/basic_io/). En esta [página](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/ofstream/ofstream/) tienes la referencia de `ofstream`.